# Bash for loop - listing files in /etc/init.d, then running command on result

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, service, dhcp

Currently I have the below script - trying to search all files in /etc/init.d, and only output those that contain dhcp. Reason for this is I need to find the applications and endpoints used in DHCP.

```
for $service in /etc/init.d/$service; do (cat /etc/init.d/$service | grep dhcp)
```

However I get a ">" following by blinking box after this is run.

1) What am I doing wrong in the script?

2) What are better ways to find all applications and endpoints of a service / protocol like dhcp?

Comment: can you be more specific about "applications and endpoints of a service"?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `grep -l dhcp /etc/init.d/*` or, with GNU `grep`: `grep -lR dhcp /etc/init.d`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Neither of the two commands brought back any results when using Mint Mate v17.3 (based on Ubuntu v14.04)

Comment: @uno I am wanting to fuzz dhcp on Ubuntu / Mint Mate, and need to find out the names and locations of all applications and other locations on the system.

Comment: Then you have no files in `/etc/init.d` that contain `dhcp`…

Comment: Ok. what launches dhcp? Where is the endpoint for dhcp - that I can send packets to?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing the **done** keyword, the correct syntax is:

```
for variable in source; do dosomething; done
```

if you write it in a script you can save yourself some semicolon:

```
for variable in source
do
   # Some work
done
```

That is why you are getting the ">".